# How to fix Linux OS is not present on Boot menu?

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, bootloader

I've tried to install several times so far Linux Mint 19 alongside Windows 10. Windows 10 is the primary OS.

I installed Linux on `/dev/sda` making manually a swap area, root and home partitions and when the installation is finished and I restart and the system boots automatically in Windows like there was a single OS installed.

What I'm doing wrong and how to fix this issue?

**UPDATE**

Before I couldn't access to Windows nor Linux, so I was able to fix the Windows boot following this steps, then the Windows boot partition now is FAT32 EFI.

```
Run command prompt from Windows installation DVD
diskpart
sel dis 0
sel par 1
del par override
cre par EFI
for fs=FAT32 quick
assign letter=T
exit
bcdboot C:\Windows /s T: /f ALL
exit

Then reboot the computer
```

Comment: Is Windows installed in UEFI mode or BIOS mode? (That is, does the Windows disk have a FAT32 "EFI system partition" with bootmgfw.efi in it, **or** does it have an NTFS "Microsoft system partition" with bootmgr in it?) And did you install Mint in the same mode?

Comment: @grawity Thanks for answer. Since before appeared for me the `Minimal Bash-Like...` menu and I couldn't access to Windows nor Linux, I used a command prompt from installation CD of Windows and sent these commands `diskpart`, `sel dis 0`, `sel par 1`, `del par override`, `cre par EFI`, `for fs=FAT32 quick`, `assign letter=T`, `exit`, `bcdboot C:\Windows /s T: /f ALL`, `exit` and after that I was able to boot in Windows, so it think is FAT32 EFI partition.